# Controls for AVPlayer

Tags: ios, avplayer

I am using `AVPlayer` to display video in my iOS app. Now I need some nice looking controls for previous, next and the play/pause button. By default `AVPlayer` doesn't come with any.

I am wondering, are there any open source components out there that I can directly use for such controls? I actually just want the same controls that `MPMoviePlayerController` uses. But I guess that is not possible, unless I counterfeit them completely.

I could create them myself but I don't want to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a really nice one. BeamApp

https://github.com/BeamApp/MusicPlayerViewController

Comment: YES!! That one is awesome! Thank you so much!