# How to hide only Next and Previous button in AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, avplayer

Is there any way to hide only Next and Previous buttons in AVPlayer while playing a video

Answer (score 2):

You can only either hide them all or show them all via the [AVPlayerViewController `showsPlaybackControls` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVPlayerViewController/showsPlaybackControls), so what I would recommend doing is using an open source or third party library or framework that controls AVPlayer for you.

Such as what's suggested [by this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850306/controls-for-avplayer), which [ultimately points to this GitHub project](https://github.com/BeamApp/MusicPlayerViewController).  You can then remove or hide the controls you don't want to be visible.

Alternatively, [you could create your own controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29090186/hide-controls-in-avplayerviewcontroller-only-at-start) that call into, and control, AVPlayer.

Answer (score 0):

=> you can get notification when ply or pause and stop
    when you got notification of play at that time you can hide both next and preivios button